# could not convert string to float: '10,000' Using Django

Tags: python, django

How do i convert string to float in django?

this is my views.py

```
def UpdateFamilyIncomes(request):
   id = request.POST.get('id')
   Amount_From = int(float(request.POST.get("Amount_From")))
   Amount_To = int(float(request.POST.get("Amount_To")))
   Family_Total_Income = FamilyTotalIncome.objects.get(id=id)
   Family_Total_Income.Amount_From = Amount_From
   Family_Total_Income.Amount_To = Amount_To
```

this is my models.py

```
class FamilyTotalIncome(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Amount_From=models.FloatField()
    Amount_To = models.FloatField()
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)
```

this is my error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma is the source of the error.
You should first replace the comma with a point.

```
value = "10,000"
floating_value = float(value.replace(',', '.'))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
float(a.replace(',',''))
```